# XML and Excel Structures, debugging and etc

Tags: python, excel, xml, debugging

I'm currently working on this project: https://github.com/lucasmolinari/unlocker-EX.
It's a excel unlocker, it works by editing the XML files inside the workbooks. (more information on the github page).
The script works fine in workbooks with almost no content inside, but recently I'm testing some bigger workbooks, and when I open the unlocked file, excel says it's corrupted and I can't find any difference between the original and the unlocked workbook, I'm 100% sure the problem is when the script change the content in the file, I watched every step of the script and it just stops working when the files are edited.

Does someone have more knowlege on how XML files work or in the structure of excel workbooks? Or like, some way to verify the differences between the original file and the edited to see if is some formatting problem..? I'm really sorry about this question, but I have no idea from where to start now, I tried everything I can.

Changed to open files in UTF-8 format and tried to find any corrupted character in the edited file,but manually is too hard to find any.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's been impossible to check every little ">" or "." sign, for what I checked the edited file is pretty similar to the original. My worries is that maybe between more than 200+ lines is a extra character making the file be corrupted. Thinking about change the way I deleted the <sheetProtection>, feels like I did it in a bad way

Comment: Do your modified XML files validate the Excel schemas? This is the easiest way to check for possible erroneous little ">" or "[![".

Comment: @AntoineL How do I validate the file with Excel Schemas? Found some syntax XML validators on the internet, and they all validate my modified XML. What is the problem them? Why does excel says it's corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

Using ElementTree library solves the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).